# How do I use persist with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm

I am attempting to get familiar with this persist package for node. Can someone tell me if the connection is being made here with persist.connect or are these properties?

```
var persist = require("persist");
var type = persist.type;

// define some model objects
Phone = persist.define("Phone", {
  "number": type.STRING
});

Person = persist.define("Person", {
  "name": type.STRING
}).hasMany(this.Phone);

persist.connect({
  driver: 'sqlite3',
  filename: 'test.db',
  trace: true
}, function(err, connection) {
  Person.using(connection).all(function(err, people) {
    // people contains all the people
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above runs without error on my system if I just change `this.Phone` to `Phone`.

`persist.connect` "connects" to a `test.db` file which contains the database.